# Robolectric and Evernotes android-job library

Tags: android, robolectric, android-jobscheduler

I'm using **Evernotes** [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library for **Scheduling jobs** and everything works fine but, when i want to run a test case that is running with **Robolecteric** i get this error :

```
com.evernote.android.job.JobManagerCreateException: All APIs are disabled, cannot schedule any job

at com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.<init>(JobManager.java:184)
at com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.create(JobManager.java:107)
at com.M.MyApp.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:63)
at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:137)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:290)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:203)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:109)
```

basically its pointing to line 63 of my application class :

```
JobManager.create(getApplicationContext()).addJobCreator(new JobMaker());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ran into this same issue after updating the Evernote library to 1.1.11

You can just wrap your initialisation of the JobManager in a try catch and swallow the exception, but a better solution is to create a test version of your application class and load that in for your tests.

The steps are described [here](http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/).

Move line 63 of your application class to a method - called something like setUpJobManager() - and call that in your onCreate. Then override that method in the test version of your application class.

```
public class TestApplication extends AppController implements TestLifecycleApplication {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void createJobManager() {

}
```

Then pass the TestApplication class to your robolectric tests. Just make sure you correctly annotate your Robolectric test classes to use the test application class.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 23, application = TestApplication.class)
```